# Accessing webreference appSettings from Biztalk BTSNTSvc.exe.config

Tags: configuration, reference, biztalk

Sometimes we use global variables in our Biztalk configuration (`BTSNTSvc.exe.config`), we add these with the following code:

```
<appSettings>
    <!--<add key="ZNA_Integratie_Prestaties_OasisProxy_OasisServiceProxy_Service"
             value="http://localhost/service.asmx" />-->
    <add key="IPSdatum" value="20090101" />
  </appSettings>
```

Using the following c# code we can read in the value:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IPSdatum"]
```

Now normally we when we add a webreference to our biztalk projects we use them through ports, however a colleague of mine used an in code webreference and so added one to a c# class project, so this means there's an `app.config` where the address is being held. However when we deploy our project there isn't an `app.config` of course. Only the `BTSNTSvc.exe.config`. I heard there is a way to add a key value to this config which can refer to the `app.config` value.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: As you've mentioned, ideally you should be using send ports in BizTalk, and not custom assemblies with web references, in which case the configuration will be stored in binding files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1:**

`BTSNTSvc.exe.config` file is a .NET config file, you can put the content what you see inside your app.config file inside the `BTSNTSvc.exe.config` file at the correct sections.

**Option 2:**

You can refer to additional config files from `BTSNTSvc.exe.config` file using the app domain concept [as explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc789004.aspx)

If you are dealing with only few entries, then option 1 is preferable.

Even better, try not to use inline web references within your helper classes, try to avoid the situation.

Comment: Yeah I know, I never do inline web references, it's in a code of an old collegue and we can't really modify it right now. I like option 1, I'll give it a try

Comment: Option 1 worked fine, thanks. In the end I had to remove it anyway, because using this service did not do any retries. So I spend an entire day rewriting his code using a biztalk sendport in the way it should be :)