# Reading configuration in Biztalk maps AND orchestrations

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I've got 2 situations in which I need to read in configuration data into BizTalk:

1. Within expression shape of orchestration. Compare a part of a message response to a predefined string which is different between environments
2. Connection string of a Database lookup in a map

I don't want to have to recompile in order to move between a test and live environment and I will have multiple applications potentially needing their own version of the same configuration element.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324868/accessing-webreference-appsettings-from-biztalk-btsntsvc-exe-config) but this is server level and seems risky.

My other idea was to use a custom table with an SP to read values back. This means that every time I want to read a setting I have to construct, send and receive a message in the orchestration. It also doesn't help me in the map.

Are there any other options which are less intrusive to the process flow or involve less work/maintenance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most frequently chosen method to store config data for BizTalk is SSO though there are certainly other options.

You can use the SSO Config Data Storage Tool, http://seroter.wordpress.com/2007/09/21/biztalk-sso-configuration-data-storage-tool/, to maintain the information.

Microsoft has published a sample helper class to read the data, http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=99741.

The BRE might also be an option to consider for the Orchestration.

Comment: If you are going to use SSO you would be better of using Microsoft's official tool https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14524    
Richard Seroter's tool has a bug in it that means the official tool can't then be used to maintain it afterwards.

Comment: is there a neat way of accessing these values in a map?

Comment: You would use the SSOHelper in a Scripting Functoid.

Comment: @boatseller as I suspected. Was hoping maybe Get Application/Common Value might be neater

Comment: You could use that if the configuration values aren't sensitive.  And you don't need to create any custom classes to use it.  I've used it mainly for translation of reference data.  See my blog http://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/biztalk-pattern-translating-reference-data-in-a-map-using-xref/

Comment: @Dijkgraaf It's worth mentioning that the official Microsoft tool doesn't work with BizTalk 2013 R2 on Windows Server 2012 R2 due to an old DLL reference.  However, Sandro Pereira has recompiled the tool's DLL and made it available here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/BizTalk-Server-2013-R2-Fix-5a790391