# Change a functiod value without redeploying orchestration?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a simply value mapping functoid with a hard-coded string value in a Biztalk Transform which I need to change. I'd rather not re-deploy and regression test an entire orchestration just for this one value. Is there any way to change this on production without re-deploying the orchestration?

Comment: In a word, no.  However there are various ways of making it configurable so that you don't have this issue again in the future.

Comment: I'm a bit new to biztalk. Afraid that was the answer. Assuming then that these sort of things are compiled with the assembly? I was hoping maybe it's stored in one of the biztalk DBs and had been looking for it.


Yes, it should be changed to pull from a config of some sort as a preventative measure and I'm vaguely familiar with some methods.

Comment: Yes, with a map it creates a XSLT file, including the hard coded values and that XSLT file gets embedded in the assembly as a string and that XSLT string gets executed during the transformation.  So no, you can't just go and update it in the BizTalk DB.

Comment: You should convert that to an actual answer and I'll mark it as the answer. :)

Comment: If I have some time I will write a fuller answer later giving the different configurable options, as a just "No you can't do it" is not an proper answer in my opinion :-)  Hence I did it in a comment.  There is an answer here that gives some of the options, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060889/reading-configuration-in-biztalk-maps-and-orchestrations?rq=1  But doesn't go into much details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. BizTalk best practices here dictate that different artifact types should be in different projects.  This allows you to deploy just the Maps assembly, like so (after unenlisting any orchestration that uses maps directly):

   ```
   btstask AddResource /A:<ApplicationName> /T:System.BizTalk:BizTalkAssembly /Ov /So:Maps.dll /Op:GacOnAdd,GacOnImport,GacOnInstall
   ```
2. When possible, put transforms on **ports** rather than in orchestrations.  This helps alleviate the problem of having to unenlist orchestrations, and should perform better, but isn't always practical (sometimes an orchestration needs to decide which map, or use multiple maps, or ...).  In a case like that, you can redeploy the maps assembly and restart your host instances without redeploying orchestrations.
3. Avoid hard coded values in maps and orchestrations.  Point them to a static variable in a static C# utility class.  The C# assembly can be redeployed without redeploying a map or orchestration (just GAC the C# assembly and restart your host instance).  The C# assembly can also be directed to point to some other storage, such as SSO, a database, a WCF/Web service, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your maps in a separate assembly and while installing you just need to GAC the map assembly. Depending on the deployment model you use, it can vary how you GAC BizTalk assembly. But if you just separate your assemblies in this way, you can isolate the change.

Comment: He's calling the map from the orchestration.  He'd still have to redeploy the orchestration.

Comment: No if orchestration is in separate assembly and does not require any change due to map change, then it won't be required

Comment: Ahh silly me.  You're right.  Just have to unenlist the orchestration.  Brainfart.

Answer (score 1):

You have two solutions : 
1 - Like said before by @Vikas isolate map and deploy just this artefact 

2 - You can and should rather put your value is a SSO Storage and retrieve it at runtime in your orchestration https://seroter.wordpress.com/2007/09/21/biztalk-sso-configuration-data-storage-tool/ so no need to redeploy at all